# "Fast" Displaying in a DocumentViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xps, documentviewer, documentpaginator

I'm building a WPF application in which I need to display document previews such as what is achievable with a DocumentViewer and DocumentPaginator. However, converting the report to XPS and loading it into a DocumentViewer has proven to be very slow when the report is large (as a common report I'll need to display is).

This lead me to start thinking that there is probably some way to start showing the first few pages of the report while the rest of the pages are being 'loaded' into the DocumentViewer -- **basically loading/showing the pages *as they're created***.

Does anyone know if something like this is possible? And, if so, how would you suggest I get started trying to make it work? I've spent a few hours looking around online for a solution to display the report faster, but haven't come up with anything.

For the sake of full disclosure, in this case the report I need to display is being created in HTML. I know that I need to convert it to XPS in order to use the DocumentViewer, but I bring this up because if anyone has a fast way of displaying the HTML, please feel free to bring that up too. I can't use a WebBrowser control as I have to have the display in a 'print preview' type of mode.  **A good algorithm for deciding how to 'paginate' an HTML site would probably lead me to a solution to this problem as well as then I could create a custom control to display it.  I'd use a DocumentPaginator, but then the outputted file is XPS and then I'm back to the DocumentViewer issue.**

Again, any help is *greatly* appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Well, shucks.  I was thinking this morning about your question yesterday and wondering if you meant something like this instead.  :)  Have you investigated any document generation libraries?  This sounds like a pretty sizable problem.

Comment: Yea, I the more I played with your solution (which was great, don't get me wrong!), the more I realized it wasn't quite what I needed and that I didn't make the problem clear in the original question. A sizable problem it has certainly been...

Comment: For what it's worth - I would avoid doing trying to roll your own solution with the DocumentPaginator for this.  It doesn't lend itself to extension very well.  The approach that comes to mind is again to use the WebBrowser control (I know, sorry!) to render the HTML and then generate a series of page-sized images from the rendered document.  I wonder if you could modify the code here to basically walk the doc, in "imgSize" increments equal to your desired page size, and generate page images that way?  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/html2image.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got something...

Once again I found a better URL to reference.  This one wasn't loading for me straight up so I grabbed it from the Google cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:LgceMCkJBrsJ:joshclose.net/%3Fp%3D247

Define the IViewObject interface as described in each article:

```
    [ComVisible(true), ComImport()]
    [GuidAttribute("0000010d-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IViewObject
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [PreserveSig]
        int Draw(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] UInt32 dwDrawAspect,
            int lindex,
            IntPtr pvAspect,
            [In] IntPtr ptd,
            IntPtr hdcTargetDev,
            IntPtr hdcDraw,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref Rectangle lprcBounds,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref Rectangle lprcWBounds,
            IntPtr pfnContinue,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] UInt32 dwContinue);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetColorSet([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwDrawAspect,
           int lindex, IntPtr pvAspect, [In] IntPtr ptd,
            IntPtr hicTargetDev, [Out] IntPtr ppColorSet);
        [PreserveSig]
        int Freeze([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwDrawAspect,
                        int lindex, IntPtr pvAspect, [Out] IntPtr pdwFreeze);
        [PreserveSig]
        int Unfreeze([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwFreeze);
        void SetAdvise([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int aspects,
          [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int advf,
          [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IAdviseSink pAdvSink);
        void GetAdvise([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] paspects,
          [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] advf,
          [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] IAdviseSink[] pAdvSink);
    }
```

Create an HtmlPaginator class that screenshots the browser's document (as described) but then crops it into pages / frames:

```
    class HtmlPaginator
    {
        public event EventHandler<PageImageEventArgs> PageReady;

        protected virtual void OnPageReady(PageImageEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<PageImageEventArgs> handler = this.PageReady;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }

        public class PageImageEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public Image PageImage { get; set; }
            public int PageNumber { get; set; }
        }

        public void GeneratePages(string doc)
        {
            Bitmap htmlImage = RenderHtmlToBitmap(doc);

            int pageWidth = 800;
            int pageHeight = 600;

            int xLoc = 0;
            int yLoc = 0;
            int pages = 0;

            do
            {
                int remainingHeightOrPageHeight = Math.Min(htmlImage.Height - yLoc, pageHeight);
                int remainingWidthOrPageWidth = Math.Min(htmlImage.Width - xLoc, pageWidth);
                Rectangle cropFrame = new Rectangle(xLoc, yLoc, remainingWidthOrPageWidth, remainingHeightOrPageHeight);

                Bitmap page = htmlImage.Clone(cropFrame, htmlImage.PixelFormat);

                pages++;
                PageImageEventArgs args = new PageImageEventArgs { PageImage = page, PageNumber = pages };
                OnPageReady(args);

                yLoc += pageHeight;

                if (yLoc > htmlImage.Height)
                {
                    xLoc += pageWidth;

                    if (xLoc < htmlImage.Width)
                    {
                        yLoc = 0;
                    }
                }
            } 
            while (yLoc < htmlImage.Height && xLoc < htmlImage.Width);
        }

        private static Bitmap RenderHtmlToBitmap(string doc)
        {
            Bitmap htmlImage = null;

            using (var webBrowser = new WebBrowser())
            {
                webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
                webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                webBrowser.DocumentText = doc;

                while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }

                webBrowser.Width = webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
                webBrowser.Height = webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;

                htmlImage = new Bitmap(webBrowser.Width, webBrowser.Height);
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(htmlImage))
                {
                    var hdc = graphics.GetHdc();

                    var rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, webBrowser.Width, webBrowser.Height);
                    var rect2 = new Rectangle(0, 0, webBrowser.Width, webBrowser.Height);

                    var viewObject = (IViewObject)webBrowser.Document.DomDocument;
                    viewObject.Draw(1, -1, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, hdc, ref rect1, ref rect2, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

                    graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
                }
            }

            return htmlImage;
        }
    }
```

Call it like so:

```
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

        while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        HtmlPaginator pagr = new HtmlPaginator();

        pagr.PageReady += new EventHandler<HtmlPaginator.PageImageEventArgs>(pagr_PageReady);

        pagr.GeneratePages(browser.DocumentText);
```

To test it I implemented a basic form with a button and a picture box and a List collection.  I add pages to the collection as they're ready from the HtmlPaginator and use the button to add the next image to the picturebox.

The magic numbers are your desired width and height.  I used 800x600 but you probably have different dimensions you want.

The downside here is you're still waiting for the WebBrowser to render the HTML but I really don't see how an alternate solution is going to reduce that time - something has to interpret and draw the HTML in the first place.  Write your own web browser I guess.  :)

I did try playing with IViewObject.Draw to see if I could just have it render the page frames directly rather than have the cropping loop, but it wasn't working for me.

Comment: So, I'm thinking I could do something very similar to this, only converting it into a group of "Visuals" or something similar for WPF. However, an interesting problem that arises now is how to handle 'inserting' headers/footers on each page and how to tell if a table was broken by a 'Page Break' (because, if so, we need to repeat the table header on the latter page).

Comment: The HtmlPaginator is using WinForms Images because that's what the sample code I started from was rendering to.  There's no reason it couldn't be invoked from a WPF app though and just transform the resulting image to a WPF drawable image.  I'll get you the solution tomorrow.

Comment: JToland - sorry I didn't get this to you Friday.  The solution is posted to GitHub here: https://github.com/mcw0933/StackOverflowQuestion5745182

Comment: Wow, that's absolutely great! I'm impressed (and very appreciative!) by the amount of time you've spent on this problem in the past couple of days.  The only issues I'll have to work out from this is inserting page headers/footers on each 'page' and how to tell if a <table> is broken over multiple pages (need to repeat the table header if so). The best way I've thought to do this is try and get the actual HTML code somehow of what's being 'displayed' by each 'page'.

Comment: Glad that was helpful.  :)  I just want to warn you though - it sounds like what you're embarking on isn't going to be a shallow amount of work.  You may want to look into seeing if any 3rd party document generation libraries do "on-the-fly" pagination.  The other (other-other) angle you might take with this is to try to simulate a printer and let the WebBrowser control (again! I'm incurable!) send the paginated document to your receiver.  Haven't played with much of the printer library stuff in .NET outside PrintTicket so I have no idea if/how you could do that.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it's going to be a major pain, but I'm not sure how to get around that. I've looked into some 3rd party solutions, but nothing I've found has really looked too promising at this point. I've not tried emulating a printer, but I'll certainly look into it. I have no idea at this point how I'd incorporate your solution for the print-preview and getting the HTML, but I can't think of any other way to handle header/footer and tables.  Really, thanks again for all the help you've provided up to now.

Comment: Well, sincerely - best of luck.  Comment back on this post when you find your complete solution, I'd love to hear about it!  But it really does sound like you're essentially rewriting your own web browser / page spooler... :)